# Converting MySQL code to PostgreSQL using foreign keys

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I am trying to create tables with a primary key and foreign key in Postgresql. Originally was created in MySQL but I do not know how to convert can someone assist.

I converted the first table but the instructor table is giving me problems

```sql
CREATE TABLE instructor_detail (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  youtube_channel VARCHAR(128) NULL,
  hobby VARCHAR(45) NULL
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS instructor;

`CREATE TABLE instructor (  
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
first_name VARCHAR(45) NULL,  
last_name VARCHAR(45) NULL,  
email VARCHAR(45) NULL,  
instructor_detail_id INT NULL,  
CREATE INDEX fk_detail_idx ON instructor (instructor_detail_id),  CONSTRAINT fk_detail FOREIGN KEY (instructor_detail_id) REFERENCES instructor_detail (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);`

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CREATE"
LINE 7:   CREATE INDEX fk_detail_idx ON instructor (instructor_detai...
```

Comment: Mention the exact error you are getting, "giving me problems" doesn't help much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The foreign key constraint will work in PostgreSQL, no change is required.

The `KEY` clause is a MySQL extension to create an index within `CREATE TABLE`, which PostgreSQL does not support.

You'll have to convert the `KEY` clause to a separate `CREATE INDEX` statement in PostgresSQL.

Comment: Like I wrote: `CREATE INDEX` is **not** part of the `CREATE TABLE` statement, but a separate SQL statement.